# How to prove that this polynomial is irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let p be a prime. How to prove that $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+1$ is irreducible over $Q[x]$?

Comment: You mean irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.  It's not a polynomial **over** $\mathbb Q[x]$, it's **in** $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Hint: Look at the polynomial obtained by replacing $x$ by $x + 1$ and use Eisenstein.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $f(x)$ this polynomial. Recall that $f(x)$ is reducible iff $f(x+1)$ is reducible.

$$f(x) = \frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1}\\ \therefore f(x+1) = \frac1{x} ((x+1)^p -1) = \frac1{x} \left( \sum_{t=1}^p {p \choose t} x^t \right) = \sum_{t=1}^p {p \choose t} x^{t-1}$$

Now use the Eisenstein criterion.